# Self-hosted website won't go online unless I SSH into the server first

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, web-hosting

I have a simple HTML page hosted on an old mac desktop (Catalina) on the in-built apache server.

The problem is when I browse to the IP on chrome after a while, the website is down. But as soon as I tunnel into the machine using SSH, it comes back online.

The apache server is running, because the `sudo apachectl start` code gives the response that it's up:

`/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: service already loaded`

I'm new to servers and I'm not sure why the website is going to sleep. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the apache log files, or any system log files?

Comment: Is the entire computer going to sleep? SSH might be waking it up via a Bonjour sleep proxy or something like that. Can you ping the server it while the web server isn't responding?